# can't we use select another column with max() in sql

Tags: sql

I have  a `table emp (ename,eid,did,sal,sex)` where column **did is foreign key** with another `table dept (did,dname)`.

I want to get the  `max sal` of the **company** along with `name and did` of the person who is getting it.

I am executing following query

```
select did,ename ,max(sal) from emp;
```

But the Result is :

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

so My question is can't I have more than 1 columns ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `MAX` aggregate function like this. Using `MAX` without a `GROUP BY` clause will just return one record with the maximum `sal` value. You are not allowed to place any more non-aggregated fields in the `SELECT` clause.

If you want to get the record having the maximum `sal` value, then you have to do a self-join:

```
select e1.*
from emp as e1
inner join (
   select max(sal) as max_sal
   from emp
) as e2 on e1.sal = e2.max_sal
```

**Note:** The above query will return more than one records from table `emp`, in case more than one records share the same maximum `sal` value.

**Edit:**

If you want to get the maximum salary *per department* then you have to include a `GROUP BY` clause in the derived table used:

```
select e1.*
from emp as e1
inner join (
   select did, max(sal) as max_sal
   from emp
   group by did
) as e2 on e1.did = e2.did and e1.sal = e2.max_sal
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to group the results by the `sal` column:

```
select did,ename,max(sal) from emp group by sal
```

Comment: This may not work as intended in Oracle, though it might work in MySQL.

Comment: You are right Tim.My intention was to have max sal per department.

Answer (score 0):

`MAX` operates over the group specified in a `GROUP BY` clause and finds the maximum value for each group.  When not specifying a set of columns to group by, it finds the max for the entire results set.

You need to find the max sal, then you can query the rows that match:

```
select did, ename, sal
from emp
where sal = (select max(sal) from emp)
```